# How to route my component on a new page on button click?

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router-dom

I'm having trouble figuring out a way to route a component on button press. I'm confused on the <Route path="/" and  parts of the code. Right now the button works but when it routes to the new page it still shows the same home page (App.js) with the new component (Store.js) rendering just under the button.

**Routing code:**

```
<BrowserRouter>
        <Link to="/" target="_blank">
          <button>
          ORDER NOW</button>
        </Link>

        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Test />} />
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
```

This is the part of my code I'm having trouble with. I didn't put an onClick handler on button for worry I might re-render something or make clashes. When routed to the new page it displays but for some reason still shows App.js.

**Store.js: (component I want to route on button click)**

```
import { Component } from 'react'


class Test extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {

    }
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
        <h2>Hope this works</h2>
        </div>
    )
}
```

}

```
export default Test
```

[Here's my code](https://codesandbox.io/s/gamer-vgmm0)

Comment: Is that CSB up-to-date? There's no routing or `Test` component code there. It also looks like you are navigating to the path you are already on, which is essentially a non-op. The `Link` is already clickable, you don't need a button in there really.

Comment: I wanted to make the button route to a blank page only rendering Store.js. So if I understand you correctly I only need the route path? It does makes sense that the `Link to` already makes the element route to the new page. Also I've never heard of a CSB before, why do I need it to be up-to-date?

Comment: CSB -> the codesandbox you linked, it didn't appear to have all the code you are referencing here in your post, and after just checking now, still is missing relevant code. It doesn't even run. `react-router-dom` doesn't route to blank pages, it routes to paths within your app that you define ahead of time. Are you saying you want to open a new window/tab in the browser and load a specific route of your app there?

Comment: Yes I'm sorry my CSB is weird for some reason I'll fix it. To answer your question yes I want the button to open new tab to render Store.js.  Right now when I press the button it still renders App.js but right under the button Store.js displays for some reason. [https://codesandbox.io/s/gamer-2-0-vgmm0]

Comment: This link should work sorry for the confusion and thanks for having patience with me. https://codesandbox.io/s/gamer-2-0-vgmm0